# Codeeval challenge : Confusion for a beginner(Mersenne Prime number)

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to know if 2047 is a Mersenne prime number ? 
Codeeval accepts solution with 2047 as a mersenne prime number. 
However when I searched online I found 2047 not to be a mersenne prime number? Could someone tell me which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

23*89 = 2047, so it's not a prime and certainly not a Mersenne prime (even though it is one less than a power of 2.) There must be a mistake in Codeeval.